# MapState values in between multiple window streams

Tags: apache-flink, flink-streaming

I have a usecase where i am aggregating values on the same key in multiple streams it looks something like below:

Input -> window(15 secs) -> window(1 min) -> window(15 min) -> ...
-> out_1        -> out_2         -> out_3

In the all the windows i have a separate KeyedProcessFunction having a MapState for all three streams, however the i am using the same name for all the instances while creating the MapStateDescriptor something like:

MapStateDescriptor<Long, Float> test =
new MapStateDescriptor<>("**test**", Long.class, SomeObject.class);

Given all the three streams have the same key on which they are operating will the mapstate will be shared between streams because it has the same name in MapStateDescriptor<>("**test**", Long.class, SomeObject.class) or it will be unique for each stream

Should i keep the name different in that case?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

State is always scoped to the function/operator in which it is used. It cannot be shared with or accessed from other functions/operators. So what you have done is fine.